# Adobe AEM/OSGI: Where do I placed my OSGI config (org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter) so it's picked up by both author and publisher?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, aem-6

as above.

---

**situation:**

I want to customize Sling referrer config (org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter) in all environments (author and publishers). I created an XML file with custom config. Thanks

---

**Tests/observations:**

1. As a test, I made copies my XML file in these 2 paths

- ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/mysite/config
- ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/mysite/configs/config

  After building the code package in my local mac, I then uploaded and installed the code package in the sandbox author but Sling referrer does not show my custom config.
  On the sandbox publisher, it's the same situation.

2. Same a test1 except that I removed the XML in the paths mentioned above and place it in this location instead

- ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/mysite/configs/config/config.author

  This time it works. I can see my custom config in sandbox author.

3. Same a test1 except that I removed the XML in the paths mentioned above and place it in this location instead

- ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/mysite/configs/config/config.publish

  This time it works. I can see my custom config in sandbox publisher.

4. In my local author AEM instance, I can placed the XML file in -any- paths mentioned above and it will work fine.

---

This is a copy of my **OSGI config**.

➜ cat org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.xml

<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
allow.hosts="[mysite.my-sso-provider.com,mysite-sandbox.my-sso-provider.com]"/>

---

**background info**: We are currently on 6.4.x. We are testing our custom code so we can upgrade to 6.5.x. AMS has provided a sandbox environment (1 author, 1 publisher, 1 dispatcher, 1 load balancer and cloudfront) for us to play around with.

Answer (score 1):

Under `/apps/your-project/config` is enough to be caught for both author and publish run modes.